# Export webcal from a Facebook page I administrate

Tags: facebook, google-calendar-api, facebook-page, facebook-events

from my private Facebook profile I created a page for the [club](https://www.facebook.com/slotcarfreundemagdeburg) I'm a member of. I now want to export all the events created on the page to a google calendar via the webcal-link. There are manuals on how to do this but the calendar link I get only contains the events of my private profile and not the club events. How can I get the club-events and not my private ones?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22491/import-sync-google-calendar-events-with-facebook-page), you can get the xml link to your Gcal in the individual calendar's settings(hover over the calendar's name in the sidebar, click the arrow that shows up, and choose "Calendar settings") and use an rss-to-Facebook service like RSS Graffiti, IFTTT, Zapier or Networked Blogs to post new items to your Facebook page. However, it is also stated that Facebook isn't a calendar management application and there's no native method of importing events.

According to this [discussion](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=281152478711315):

> Click "Discussion" then click "Write Post". This is not the same as embedding, but it's the only option for group members. If you are the group administrator, you can put the link in the description (on the right).

You can check this [tutorial](http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/how-to-sync-facebook-events-with-google-calendar/217279) on how to sync Facebook events with Google Calendar. You can also check this [site](https://zapier.com/zapbook/facebook-pages/google-calendar/) to integrate Facebook pages and Google Calendar.

Comment: Thank a lot - all does not work like I really expected it. Zapier would be a solution if there where ONLY events on the facebook side. I think I will now do it the other way around and create goolge calender entries and then Zapier will post those as Facebook events.